# I have lost my superuser rights for installation. What can I do now?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, sudo

I've recently started using Ubuntu on my old laptop and I actually really like this OS, but somehow I've lost my superuser rights and idk how and why. As you can see in the screenshot, I've already tried to install the package with "sudo dpkg -i 'package name'" and the terminal didn't install anything and showed "Setting up nordvpn-release (1.0.0) ..." instead.

I really have no clue, what's behind all of this and how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Everything is ok with your superuser rights, the package has been installed (`Setting up nordvpn-release (1.0.0)`) and your command finished without error, so it's installed.

Comment: I don't see any problems here. Is there anything else supporting your theory or any other information about the problems you are having? Maybe this is an XY problem? Also, please do not submit pictures of text. It's hard to read and impossible to work with.  Instead, copy/paste and add [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) on the line before and the line after the pasted content. Don't change anything inside the paste.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu users when created don't have 'superuser' on their own.  That's why `sudo` exists to execute commands with elevated privileges.

Nothing's wrong here, you have no 'loss of rights'; you just have to use `sudo`.